# OpenGL - Buffer updates next rendering object

Tags: c++, opengl

Okej, so i got a really odd case where i have three(or two, doesnt matter) objects and one of them is updating its buffer to "animate". In other words, one object is moving and the other(s) stands still. The odd part comes in when the moving object is moving but the object that is rendering after the moving object is accually animating. The moving object moves but does not animate. Hope it makes sense.

Now some code and since i have troubleshooting it to be buffer related i will those parts:

```
Object::Object() {
    ...
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO_);
    glGenBuffers(2, VBO_); 
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO_);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO_);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 4 * 3, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 4 * 2, tex_vert, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO_);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * 6, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);                       // unbind vertex
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);           // unbind buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);   // unbind buffer
}
void Object::Update() {
    ...
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_[1]);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(float) * 4 * 2, tex_vert);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
void Object::Render() {
    ...
    glUseProgram(Shader_.GetProgramID());
    glBindVertexArray(VAO_);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture_);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

int Main() {
    Object m();
    Object m2();
    Object m3();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(engine.window)) {
        ...
        m.Update();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        m.Render();
        m3.Render();
        m2.Render();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        ...
    }
}
```

So m3 get anitmated but m is moving, and if a change place with m3 and m2, m2 will get animated. If i dont render m2/m3, m will get animation and moving. Worth mentioning, all non-animating objects get the texture but will stay in init state, so everything looks good at the beginning.

VAO, VBO and EBO got different values for each object but yet, "wrong" buffer(VBO_[1]) get updated.

Think i tried most of the wrong ways of solving this so it would be really appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

Edit:

Addition info regarding how the buffers are filled etc.

```
void Object::Update() {
    if (Keyboard::KeyPressed(GLFW_KEY_W)) {
        if (MovementY_ < 0) {
            MovementY_ = 0;
        }
        MovementY_ += MovementSpeed_ * Engine::GetDeltaTime();

        TextureTopLeft_      = glm::vec2((MALE_TEXTURE_SIZE_S * SpriteFrame_) - MALE_TEXTURE_SIZE_S,    MALE_UP_STAND_T - MALE_TEXTURE_SIZE_T);
        TextureTopRight_     = glm::vec2((MALE_TEXTURE_SIZE_S * SpriteFrame_),                          MALE_UP_STAND_T - MALE_TEXTURE_SIZE_T);
        TextureBottomLeft_   = glm::vec2((MALE_TEXTURE_SIZE_S * SpriteFrame_) - MALE_TEXTURE_SIZE_S,    MALE_UP_STAND_T);
        TextureBottomRight_  = glm::vec2((MALE_TEXTURE_SIZE_S * SpriteFrame_),                          MALE_UP_STAND_T);
    }
    float tex_vert[4][2] = {
        {TextureTopRight_.s,      TextureTopRight_.t},
        {TextureBottomRight_.s,   TextureBottomRight_.t},
        {TextureBottomLeft_.s,    TextureBottomLeft_.t},
        {TextureTopLeft_.s,       TextureTopLeft_.t},
    };
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_[1]);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(float) * 4 * 2, tex_vert);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    PositionX_ += MovementX_;
    PositionY_ += MovementY_;
}
void Object::Render() {
    glm::mat4 Projection, Model;
    Projection = glm::orthoLH(0.0f, float(Engine::GetFrameBufferWidth()), 0.0f, float(Engine::GetFrameBufferHeight()), 0.0f, 1000.0f);

    Model = glm::translate(Model, glm::vec3(PositionX_, PositionY_, PositionY_));
    glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * Model;
    GLint MVP = glGetUniformLocation(Shader_.GetProgramID(), "MVP");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MVP, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvp));

    glUseProgram(Shader_.GetProgramID());
    glBindVertexArray(VAO_);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture_);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

# These two never change, assigned in object-creation.
float vertices[4][3] = {
    {+SpriteWidth_, +SpriteHeight_, 0.0f},
    {+SpriteWidth_, -SpriteHeight_, 0.0f},
    {-SpriteWidth_, -SpriteHeight_, 0.0f},
    {-SpriteWidth_, +SpriteHeight_, 0.0f},
};

unsigned int indices[] = {
    2, 1, 0,
    2, 0, 3,
};
```

Fragment shader:

```
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main() {
    FragColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
out vec2 TexCoord;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main() {
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

Comment: Updated the question with more information but can you please collaborate why you feel this information is needed? It was missing because i thought it cluttered the real example. The problem is not regarding if the object is in the wrong place, but why objects that do not run the update function get new information from the "tex_vert".

Comment: for crying out loud. you do see that it is a fragment shader so assume its a typo. if you dont want to understand the problem then feel free to ignore this question. The animating part is in the question. have now updated the second part with information regarding movement, which again never was the issue. Animating part, which is "tex_vert", updates objects which never run the update-function where the updating code is. So howcome VBO_[1] "points" to and updates the wrong object, that is the question.

Comment: Are you actually asking me to update the question with more code and then mocking me of writing bad one or is there a real question regarding changing the texture attributes in every frame? Is it inefficient to update the array in every frame, sure, does it change the outcome, no. Again, in case you dont want to help me understans what goes wrong, feel free to move along with your day.

Comment: First of all, I'm not shy to apologize if I misunderstood your intention. Your solution works more then fine! Im forever grateful for your help, again, sorry for the attitude :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not regarding the update of VBO_[1], aka the texture position of which should be rendered.

```
# Correct
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_[1]);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(float) * 4 * 2, tex_vert);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

The problem was that the movement/position, aka the MVP, did not update the correct object due to the missplacement of glUseProgram. First object get an empty MVP, second object get the first objects MVP, third object get the second objects MVP, first object get the third objects MVP etc. If glUseProgram(0) had been used in the end of the rendering function, none of the objects would have been placed correctly, since MVP never got a real value.

```
# Updated with correct position of glUseProgram()

glm::mat4 Projection, Model;
Projection = glm::orthoLH(0.0f, float(Engine::GetFrameBufferWidth()), 0.0f, float(Engine::GetFrameBufferHeight()), 0.0f, 1000.0f);

Model = glm::translate(Model, glm::vec3(PositionX_, PositionY_, PositionY_));
glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * Model;
GLint MVP = glGetUniformLocation(Shader_.GetProgramID(), "MVP");

glUseProgram(Shader_.GetProgramID()); // This must be loaded before UniformMatrix4fv
glUniformMatrix4fv(MVP, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvp));
glBindVertexArray(VAO_);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture_);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

So, notes to others who get confused:

`glUseProgram()` BEFORE `glUniformMatrix4fv()`

**Thanks to Rabbid76 who found the solution!**